Labeling form elements of bootstrap 4 form row breaks layout
With the following bootstrap 4.6 markup:


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="card mt-3">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h4 class="card-title">Create new cron
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary fk-reload">Refresh</button>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <label for="fk-cron-name">Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fk-cron-name" name="cron_name" placeholder="My Cron" title="Enter the unique name for your new cron"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <label for="fk-cron-spec">Spec</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fk-cron-spec" name="cron_spec" placeholder="*/5 1,2,3 * * *" title="Enter the the spec of your new cron"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <label for="fk-submit-cron">Actions</label>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="fk-submit-cron">
                                Create
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>




I expect a row style form where two text inputs are followed by a button, with each form element described by a label directly above it. If I squeeze the width of the form  (by resizing the browser window) it all lines up perfectly as I expect it, but given full width, the label above the button sneaks down in front and breaks the whole layout.
What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this in the bootstrapista way?

Buttons don't take a label so they don't have the behaviour you expect when given one

The input fields go below their label, because the form-control class gives them width: 100%. You could add that same class to your button, or set the width yourself. Or, if perhaps you will have multiple such action buttons, which you want inline, but below the label, you could give the label display: block. But as mentioned, buttons don't usually have a label, so it might make more sense to replace it with a different element to begin with.
